# Removing @InvocableMethod from a referenced method in ProcessBuilder changes the ProcessBuilder

Tags: process-builder, invocable-method

Basically the title explains everything.

I had a process builder calling an invocable method in apex. I updated the class to remove the invocableMethod annotation and the proccesss builder action has changed TOTALLY, and this logic has dissapeared.

In the flow-meta.xml metadata xml the main difference is:

BEFORE:

```
<actionName>cps_Helper</actionName>
<actionType>apex</actionType>
```

AFTER:

```
<actionName>01p0N00000CJADfNotFound</actionName>
<actionType xsi:nil="true"/>
```

So my question is, do you find this an expected behaviour? Have you ever experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, all logic related to removed apex @InvocableMethod get removed from the Process Builder as well.